# Where can I find my Bitcoin core key?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lost-bitcoins

I bought some bitcoins a few years ago using Bitcoin Core.

I have since discarded my computer as it broke.

Where/how can I find my bitcoins?

Comment: quick reply: in your backup, you should have a file called "wallet.dat". No backup = no keys = lost funds. Search the forum, there are many questions like yours... You might then answer the qwuestion yourself, so it can get closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized.  There is no way to provide a canonical answer since it depends on your prior actions, such as taking a backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you recover your `wallet.dat` file, you can import it into a working bitcoin node and sweep the wallet. You must have access to the hard drive of the broken computer.

Your `wallet.dat` file can be located at:
**Linux** 
`~/.bitcoin/`
**Mac** 
`~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`
**Windows**
`%APPDATA%\Bitcoin`

You can also import the `.dat` file into `blockchain.com` which naturally I do not recommend since it defeats the purpose of decentralization.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, as the computer was thrown away, I do not have access to the hard drive. Can I not access them online somehow?

Comment: If you can access them online, someone else can too. Unless you, today, hold the private keys to the wallet you lost, those bitcoins are gone in a limbo forever.

Comment: Is there no way of accessing them using my email, payment details or computer reference?