# Retrieve Bitcoin wallet details

Tags: address

We have a bitcoin wallet which we tried to update as it was dormantfor some 8 years plus but we were unable to do so as we haven’t got the Bitcoin wallet details.

Is there any way of retrieving my Bitcoin wallet details as we don’t have the wallet ID details.

Comment: What website or software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find my Bitcoin core key?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63638/where-can-i-find-my-bitcoin-core-key)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the hard drive or computer, you can follow the steps [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63638/where-can-i-find-my-bitcoin-core-key/63660#63660) to recover your wallet.